# Do you need a child theme for Woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce

If you have a WordPress website, with a DIVI theme (and DIVI child theme), plus Woocommerce plugin, do you also need a Woocommerce child theme please?

Answer (score 0):

No, because your Woocommerce is integrated within your wordpress.

Comment: Thanks Mimmetico, so if you need to make some changes to the WC checkout page, where would you do that please?

Comment: Well, you can set up normally your checkout page in: pages-> [Your-checkout page] or in Woocommerce -> Settings. Additionally, you can customizer your checkout page programmatically in this way: https://hollerwp.com/customize-woocommerce-checkout-page/ .your settings will be retained on your child theme.